# Matching single character word with Scriptaculous Autocompleter

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, scriptaculous

I'm using the Scriptaculous Autocompleter to search a set of film titles but it's not matching single character titles such as "M" even though it starts searching after one character has been entered. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your Ajax request firing then the odds are that your issue is with your server side-script. 1 char is the default amount with Ajax.Autocompleter so that wouldn't be the issue. It could be that you are using a searching algorithm in your server side script that requires more than 1 character. For example, MySQL fulltext has a default minimum character limit of 4 characters.